# Certain Aspects of a Website Are Being Blocked When Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to create a script to login and post an ad. However when directing selenium either the  "post an ad" page or the "login" page, the URL doesn't load, and gives me a solid white screen. However when I direct the URL to the homepage or any other page, other than the ones already listed, the website loads just fine.

My problem solving:
I have read that my IP might have got blocked, however when I change my public IP address through my router, the problem persists.

I am currently unsure if the source of the problem stands from my IP or the possibly the website's scripts are only meant to detect and block scripts on certain pages.

I am also using chromedriver version 81.0.4044.69 and Chrome version Version 81.0.4044.129 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Here is my code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('https://www.kijiji.ca/t-login.html?targetUrl=L3Atc2VsZWN0LWNhdGVnb3J5Lmh0bWw/XnIrUFRKMS9oU1cxc29PdXAxbjUveFE9PQ--')
```

The result, and no errors
[Blank White Screen Found When Running The Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Q17.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try faking the user-agent (some sites really are picky in regards to that) using [this](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/) module

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

options = Options()
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)
options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={userAgent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: You can see which user-agents are allowed in the robots.txt file of a page. (would be https://www.kijiji.ca/robots.txt in this case)

Comment: I have tried your integration. I can see the user-agent cycling every time I launch, but the problem persists. I have also found that when accessing the link in a normal chrome tab, it loads fine. Does that mean that my IP is not banned/blocked?

Comment: Changing this line does the job for me
options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={userAgent}')